# Pandas `read_csv` Method Is Using Too Much RAM

Tags: python, pandas, csv, scikit-learn

I am currently playing with [Rotten Tomatoes dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/c/sentiment-analysis-on-movie-reviews) on **Kaggle** while using **pandas** `DataFrame()` to manipulate the data.

I have implemented `CountVectorizer()` from **sklearn** to extract the features (the size is 5000). I have then saved 100k rows of features and labels to a **.csv**. To be more precise, **.csv** has in total 100k rows and 5001 columns. 
Its size is about 1gb of memory.

When I have tried to read the **.csv** the problem arose:

```
pd.read_csv('train.csv', header=0, 
             delimiter=",", engine='c', na_filter=False, dtype=np.int64)
```

`CSV` parser has used too much RAM. I had 8gb of RAM on my system, which apparently was not enough.

Is there any way to reduce RAM usage? I am not constrained to **pandas** library.

Comment: well `pandas` is an in-memory data manipulation framework, and afaik with machine learning you need the whole dataset to train not chunks so you either need to move to the cloud or reduce the number of features you have.

Comment: @aws_apprentice actually i can(and i do) use chunks. I.e. incremental learning. Some classifiers in `scikit-learn` have `partial_fit` method(i'm using SGDClassifier, and it has it), so you can train classifier by chunks.

Comment: You could parse the data in chunks (or individual lines), converting each chunk to a `scipy.sparse.csr_matrix`.

Comment: like I said I am not too familiar with machine learning so I wouldn't know. if you can read it in chunks then `pandas` comes with a `chunksize` option which you can further optimize by making into a generator so you don't hold too much data in memory at once.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try using the `chunksize` option within `pandas.read_csv`.  It will allow you to process the data in batches and avoid having to load all the data into memory at once.  When you're processing each batch you can strip out any unnecessary columns and save the data in a new, slimmer object you can fit into memory.  An example is below:

```
chunks = pd.read_csv('train.csv', header=0, delimiter=",", engine='c', na_filter=False, dtype=np.int64, chunksize=50000)

slim_data = []
for chunk in chunks:
    {do your processing here}
final_data = pd.concat(slim_data)
```

In the example each chunk is 50,000 records in the format of a pandas DataFrame.  Then you iterate across each chunk of 50,000 records where you can do your processing for each chunk and append the processed DataFrame to a new object (`slim_data` as an example above), then concatenate all the chunks together into a final DataFrame you can use in your modeling.

To reiterate, the above will only work if in your processing of each batch of data you are removing data elements or representing the data elements in a more efficient manner, otherwise you will again run into memory issues.  This will, however, get you around having to load all the data at once into memory.