# Python consumes 8GB of memory when reading Excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas

The code is the following:

```
import openpyxl
import pandas as pd

def copy_csv_to_xlsx(shipment_all, shipment_truck, stockflow_all, stockflow_truck, xlsx_file):

    shipment_all_df = pd.read_csv(shipment_all)
    shipment_truck_df = pd.read_csv(shipment_truck)
    stockflow_all_df = pd.read_csv(stockflow_all)
    stockflow_truck_df = pd.read_csv(stockflow_truck)
    
    
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(xlsx_file)
    
    
    ws = wb["0. Shipment"]
    ws.append(shipment_all_df.columns)
    for row in shipment_all_df.itertuples(index=False):
        ws.append(row)
    
    ws = wb["0. Truck Shipment"]
    ws.append(shipment_shave_care_df.columns)
    for row in shipment_shave_care_df.itertuples(index=False):
        ws.append(row)
        
    ws = wb["0. SF"]
    ws.append(stockflow_all_df.columns)
    for row in stockflow_all_df.itertuples(index=False):
        ws.append(row)
        
    ws = wb["0. Truck SF"]
    ws.append(stockflow_truck_df.columns)
    for row in stockflow_truck_df.itertuples(index=False):
        ws.append(row)
    
    
    wb.save(xlsx_file)
    

copy_csv_to_xlsx("Shipment All.csv", "Shipment Trucks.csv", "Stockflow All.csv", "Stockflow Truck.csv", "Business Split Data.xlsx")
```

It really does consume 8GB of memory and never finishes. What can be the reason and how do you think I can fix this problem? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Ive had lots of problems previously opening large excel files in python, It loads the entire spreadsheet in memory before doing anything and also uses a bunch of memory when parsing the files.

Have you tried reading one csv/excel file at time, rather than load all of them at the start of your function

Comment: And try using the chunksize option https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45532711/pandas-read-csv-method-is-using-too-much-ram

Comment: See simpler approaches which do not involve row-by-row [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17684610/python-convert-csv-to-xlsx)